# Sharepoint Online REST strange error (400) - "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Since Sep 9, 2020 we started to get strange error on REST API call to get list of sub-sites and their lists:

```
GET <site url>_api/web?$expand=webs,lists,AllProperties,ThemeInfo,SiteUsers,RoleDefinitions&$select=*,webs/Url,lists/Id,lists/Title,lists/Description,lists/BaseType,lists/BaseTemplate,lists/Hidden,lists/Language,lists/ItemCount,lists/Created,lists/TemplateFeatureId,lists/CurrentChangeToken,SiteUsers/id,SiteUsers/Title,SiteUsers/LoginName,AllProperties/DesignPreviewThemedCssFolderUrl
```

The API call was working already for few year but something is broken now and in many our customers (not all , but about 30%) we see this error.

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147467261, System.ArgumentNullException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key"}}}
```

Now, we don't ask for any parameter "key", so not sure why it's null, but I found that if I remove the last part

```
AllProperties/DesignPreviewThemedCssFolderUrl
```

And request now looks :

```
GET <site url>_api/web?$expand=webs,lists,AllProperties,ThemeInfo,SiteUsers,RoleDefinitions&$select=*,webs/Url,lists/Id,lists/Title,lists/Description,lists/BaseType,lists/BaseTemplate,lists/Hidden,lists/Language,lists/ItemCount,lists/Created,lists/TemplateFeatureId,lists/CurrentChangeToken,SiteUsers/id,SiteUsers/Title,SiteUsers/LoginName
```

Then this request is returns fine, without any error

@Sharepoint team, maybe some new versions was deployed and some behaviour changes / bugs were introduced ?
Please advise,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this could be because of URL length Max limit in SharePoint.
Path length limit in SharePoint Online is 400 characters.
Path length limit in SP 2013 on-Prem is 255 characters.

Try to remove unnecessary columns or make the url shorter by URL shorteners.

Comment: Well, when I'm removing AllProperties/DesignPreviewThemedCssFolderUrl I still far way after 500 characters, but's working without. And few more things - it was working before Sep 10. And another it's a file path, we know about file path length limitation.